# Accessing struct in C file

Tags: c, struct

Just started C, working with header file declarations and such. I'm trying to write a test program that takes name and degree value for a temperature from a struct, such as 37 Kelvin and then converts that into a desired temperature.
I wrote some typedef, struct and enum declarations in my header file, but now I'm having a hard time accessing them from the main file. The error that I'm getting is **"error: request for member 'lampotila' in something not a structure or union"**

My header file is as following:

```
#ifndef asteet_h
#define asteet_h

typedef float Lampotila;
typedef char Asteikko[20];
struct Lampotila {
    Lampotila lampotila;
    Asteikko asteikko;

};



enum Asteikko{
Celsius = 1,
Fahrenheit = 1,
Kelvin = 1
};
float muunna(Lampotila,Asteikko);
#endif
```

And my main operation looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "asteet.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

float muunna(Lampotila a, Asteikko b){
    if(a.asteikko == "Celsius" && b == "Fahrenheit"){
        return(a.lampotila*1.8+32);
    }
    else if(a.asteikkko == "Fahrenheit" && b == "Celsius"){
        return((a.lampotila-32)/1-8);
    }
    else if(a.asteikko == "Celsius" && b == "Kelvin"){
        return(a.lampotila + 273.15);
    }
    else if(a.asteikkko == "Kelvin" && b == "Celsius"){
        return(a.lampotila - 273.15);
    }
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to run it with the following test data:

```
Lampotila a = {23.5, Celsius};
Lampotila b = {79.7, Fahrenheit};
Lampotila c = {285.8, Kelvin};
Asteikko kelvin = Kelvin;
printf("23.5 C on %.2f K\n", muunna(a, kelvin));
printf("79.7 F on %.2f C\n", muunna(b, Celsius));
```

Comment: Your function is declared inside main and you have the same name for the typedef of float and your struct. You also cannot compare strings with `==`, you need `strcmp`. Do yourself a favour get a book. There are plenty of errors in this code, which you will have straightened out after a couple of chapters.

Comment: None of this code makes any sense. When programming, you can't "take a guess". You actually have to understand what every single line you write does.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the following issues.

1. When you use a structure, specify struct key word or you should typedef the `struct <structure name>`
   so  the line "`float muunna(Lampotila a, Asteikko b){`" will be "`float muunna(struct Lampotila a, Asteikko b){`". This will clear your error.
2. `else if(a.asteikkko == "Fahrenheit" && b == "Celsius"){` is wrong as `asteikkko` has only 2 '`k`'s defined in your structure.
3. You can define the function outside of main and call the function by passing the arguments.